# Android - Get text from clipboard whenever user copy to clipboard

Tags: android, clipboard, copy-paste

Is there anyway that I can copy from clipboard, whenever the user copy some texts to clipboard in any application?
Should I use services in my code?

Also is it possible to implement the way for api<11 ?

tnx in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check out the [Clipboard Manager in Android](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-tutorial/clipboard-example-in-android-development/)

**Clipboard** Contents is lightweight clipboard manager for Android. The app can read contents from the clipboard history so that they can be copied into the clipboard again. Then you can edit, delete, and even share the links. Furthermore, while sharing links you can also shorten them provided URL is installed. The app automatically detects any links in the contents and provides relevant options so that you’ll be able to open or share them directly from the device.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look developers android website. They have a Service called CLIPBOARD_SERVICE

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste.html